# Flutter: Get photos/videos from instagram posts and show as horizontal list view

Tags: flutter, instagram

In my App i'm trying to get the my Instagram Page Posts' photos/videos and show them as a horizontal listview. i have tried the insta_html_parser 0.1.1 example at:
[enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/insta_html_parser#-example-tab-)

but it only gives me the last pic of the link. i just want all the Posts Links to be parsed and show me in a horizontal listview.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Widget> _widgetsList = [];
List<String> _imagesList = [];
List<String> _postsUrls = await InstaParser.postsUrlsFromProfile(
    'https://www.instagram.com/coderbau');

if (_postsUrls != null) {
  Map<String, String> photosUrls = new Map<String, String>();
  for (var item in _postsUrls) {
    Map<String, String> photosUrls =
        await InstaParser.photoUrlsFromPost(item);

    var smallimage = photosUrls['small'];

    if (smallimage != null) {
      _widgetsList.add(Image.network(photosUrls['small']));
    }
  }
  setState(() => _parsedWidgets = _widgetsList);
}
```